# How to bind images to a list where the grid that is nesting the images has a different bindingcontext?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am currently working with a list that i bind through my viewmodel and then a service.
In the list i bind an image and a label. I can successfully get the label binded, but the image does not show. The reason for this seems to be because i change the bindingcontext in the grid where the image is nested inside. I change the bindingcontext in order to get an accurate width for the image.

If i move the image outside the grid, then it shows, so now i am trying to get the bindingcontext in order again.

What i tried to do with the image was to add a new bindingcontext

`BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=gridFollowers}" Source="{Binding image}"`
where `gridFollowers` is what i name my stacklayout where the original binding is made, but unfortunately the image still does not show.

here is the full code:

```
             <StackLayout x:Name="gridFollowers"
             BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding headerService.CurrentHeader}">
             <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate >
             <DataTemplate>
                <Grid WidthRequest="75">

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                   <RowDefinition Height="8*" />
                   <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="7.5*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Grid
                     Grid.Row="0"
                     Grid.Column="0"
                     BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=headerImage}"
                     WidthRequest="{Binding Height}">

                     <ffimageloading:CachedImage
                      x:Name="headerImage" BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=gridFollowers}"
                      Source="{Binding image}" />
                </Grid>

                <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
                       Text="{Binding firstname}" />

             </DataTemplate>
             </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
             </StackLayout>
```

How can i make it so the image shows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try your code and modify some code as following, please replace your code.

```
 <Grid
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        WidthRequest="{Binding Height, Source={x:Reference headerImage}}">
                        <ffimageloading:CachedImage x:Name="headerImage" Source="{Binding image}" />
                    </Grid>
```

**Update:**

1. please check headerService.CurrentHeader data.
2. Please check if binding viewmodel to page.cs bindingcontext by code behind.

   ```
                   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                       <RowDefinition Height="8*" />
                       <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
                   </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                       <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                       <ColumnDefinition Width="7.5*" />
                   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                   <Grid
                       Grid.Row="0"
                       Grid.Column="0"
                       WidthRequest="{Binding Height, Source={x:Reference headerImage}}">
                       <ffimageloading:CachedImage x:Name="headerImage" Source="{Binding image}" />
                   </Grid>

                   <Label
                       Grid.Row="1"
                       Grid.Column="0"
                       Text="{Binding firstname}" />
               </Grid>
           </DataTemplate>
       </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
   </StackLayout>

    public partial class Page8 : ContentPage
    {

   public ObservableCollection<imagemodel> models { get; set; }
   public Page8 ()
   {
       InitializeComponent ();

       models = new ObservableCollection<imagemodel>()
       {
           new imagemodel(){firstname="first image", image="a1.jpg"},
           new imagemodel(){firstname="second image",image="a2.jpg"}
       };
       this.BindingContext = this;
   }
    }

   public class imagemodel
   {
   public string firstname { get; set; }
   public string image { get; set; }
   }
   ```

Comment: still issue when i change to that

Comment: @Carlos, it so strange, I have post the entire sample, please take a look the update.

Comment: will check it, 1sce

Comment: having a hard time making it work. if i put it outside the grid, then it shows (the imaeg). so strange?

Comment: @Carlos, Do you try my code? I don't have any issue, the image display successfully, I think it is not related to grid.

Comment: i have my list in a service that i bind to. not in viewmodel

Comment: @Carlos, So I suggest you can get data by service in ViewModel, for example, you can get data into models like my code, then binding this Viewmodel to page.

Comment: yeah i can do that, but then i would add an additional list. for some reason when i add things inside that list grid (with the iamge) - then the bindingcontext is lost. if i put the image outside of it, it shows

Comment: @Carlos,Can you provide your code at github, I will download your sample to test.